# What is the Avaya command to find out how long a port has been down for?

Tags: switch, command, downtime, avaya

I am trying to find out how i can display the up time/down time on Avaya switch ports

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to show it in the CLI, it's not in the output of `show interfaces verbose` or `show port-statistics` afaik...

Another option could be to query it using SNMP. Avaya supports the IF-MIB, and the ifTable entries contain an `ifLastChange` value (.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.9):

> The value of sysUpTime at the time the interface entered its current
>   operational state.  If the current state was entered prior to the last
>   re-initialization of the local network management subsystem, then this
>   object contains a zero value.

Note that this value is in "ticks", or 1/100ths of a second.